# Reading multiple JSON objects data from a JSON file into Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, databricks

```
My JSON data looks like this:

{
   'ABC': 5,
   'TXZ':45,
   'QWE':'Williams'
}
{
   'ABC': 8,
   'TXZ':47,
   'QWE':'David'
}
{
   'ABC': 7,
   'TXZ':63,
   'QWE':'Peter'
}
```

Please help me to load this data into dataframe using Pandas or pyspark

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(your_json)` should work is your json inside a list?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use

```
pd.read_json('{"ABC": 5, "TXZ": 45, "QWE": "Williams"}\n{"ABC": 8, "TXZ": 47, "QWE": "David"}', lines=True)
```

Please read more at here http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/io.html#io-json-reader